# How to put javascript array into MVC Model View array?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In one view i create an array in javascript that contains ids of elements and now i want to pass them into model field in my MVC Model does anybody already meet ith this kind of problem this is my model:

```
public class AppointmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int[] PersonsIds { get; set; }
    public int[] CompaniesIds { get; set; }
}
```

and in view i keep both arrays as hidden fields

```
@html.hiddenfor(model => model.PersonsIds)
@html.hiddenfor(model => model.CompaniesIds)
```

so the schema looks like this:

```
javascript->model->submit model->controller
```

Please any help would be appreciate

Comment: all things that rendered by razor would be a string, so you need somehow stringify your array, you can do that for e.g. with JSON.net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.8) and then just render that string in hiddenFor

Comment: also you can stick to asp.net mvc notation of arrays ("name"="CompaniesIds[index]") and render hidden field for each id in companiesId's it will release you from writing custom binder, but will add a lot of markup to rendered page

Comment: You can create an editortemplate for type of int[] or with a UIHint Attribute.... The thing is that on post back, your customized string will not be able to be parsed again in the array, so you need to create a custom model binder that will get post back values and store them back into an array of int... I don't have any code sample for this... so I can't help you more... but it's definitely the way to do in MVC

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to figure out how to enable the model to be posted back this is how I would do it.

As you are binding back primitive types in your collections you simply need to add inputs with the same name as your collection and the model binder will pick them up.

As a simple example, if your view renders the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PersonsIds" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="PersonsIds" value="4" />
```

This will be posted back as this:

```
PersonsIds=1&PersonsIds=4
```

The model binder will pick them up and convert them to a collection of ints.

Here is a simple example to see the model binding in action with dummy data, you will simply need to render the hidden values with javascript before posting back.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach(var personId in Model.PersonsIds)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("PersonsIds", personId)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      return View(new AppointmentModel { PersonsIds = new int[] { 1, 4 } });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AppointmentModel model)
{
     return View(model);
}
```

**Posted data populated**
[image]

**Javascript to update hidden values**

```
<input type="text" id="IdToAdd" />
<button >Add</button>
<input type="hidden" name="PersonsIds" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="PersonsIds" value="4" />
<script>
$(function() {
   $('button').click(function() {
           $(this).after('<input type="hidden" name="PersonIds" value="' + $('#IdToAdd').val()  + '" />');
  });

});
</script>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paaon1qm/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
@model AppointmentModel

@for(var i = 10; i < model.PersonsIds.Length; i++)
{<p>Line 
    @html.hiddenfor(model => model.PersonsIds[i])
</p>}
```

or for example

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model[i].Id) @Model[i].Name  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].Quantity) <br/>
}
```